# Will Mir display server be able to launch X11 applications?

Tags: xorg, compatibility, mir

I've checked [the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MirSpec) but Xorg is not even mentioned there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was searching the wrong words, this feature is [planned](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MirSpec#Toolkit_Integration_.26_Legacy_X_Application_Support) for [October 2013](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MirSpec#October_2013).

*The most prominent toolkit choices* which include *Qt/QML, GTK3, XUL etc.* will get native support, others - an *in-session rootless X server that is integrated with Mir*.

Comment: Interesting, will this be reminiscent of how mac handles X11 applications? (It launches x server that is its own program)

Answer (score 10):

The Mir server will not be able to communicate with X applications but you will be able to run the Xorg server with a Mir backend that bridges X applications to Mir. This is the same solution as done in Apple (XQuartz), Wayland (XWayland) etc. The server will be called XMir.

Comment: And this will be the way all GTK applications will be running with Mir?